# How can I solve this indentation error in Python 3?

Tags: python, debugging

I'm a beginner in python but I need to fix this small mistake. I tried different ways to fix it by changing the indentation. Maybe I'm overlooking something? The error is attached. Any help is much appreciated! Thank you

```
if(pretrained_weights):

    model.load_weights(pretrained_weights)

print('*************Using pretrained weights****************')

    return model
```

---

```
 return model
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Comment: Either indent `print()` or unindent `return` will depend on what the logic is intended to be.

Comment: Please indent `print()` and align with `return` statement if logic wants the return to be under the if clause.

Comment: `return` is invalid outside of a function. Your print is not properly indented... but is this supposed to be part of a function?

Comment: def unet(pretrained_weights = None,input_size = (256,256,1)):
  

if(pretrained_weights):
        model.load_weights(pretrained_weights)
        print('*************Using pretrained weights****************')
        return model

Comment: I added a small section of the code I'm working with. There is a function attached as you can see. Thank you all

Comment: "I tried different ways to fix it by changing the indentation." - it is no use to just try things, without any understanding. Before you can start this, you must ask yourself: "**what is the rule that tells me**, how the indentation should work? What is the **purpose** of indenting the code, and what is the **meaning** that comes from a given part of the code having certain indentation?"

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
if(pretrained_weights):
    model.load_weights(pretrained_weights)
    print('*************Using pretrained weights****************')
    return model
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are a beginner or not but hope this helps:

```
if(pretrained_weights):
    model.load_weights(pretrained_weights)
    print('*************Using pretrained weights****************')
    return model
```

Answer (score -1):

My solution:

```
if(pretrained_weights):
    model.load_weights(pretrained_weights)
    print('*************Using pretrained weights****************')
    return model
```